# Simulator is not working for smart home action with all configured session

Tags: actions-on-google

I have follow the documentation, and I created a pkg json like this and the simulator is not working I create this post to change the information with Google community.

https://plus.google.com/communities/105684267327487893574/stream/1dec6e34-163c-4f1a-883a-548cff52b522

The doc I sued to create the smart home is : https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#request

```
{
  "actions": [{
    "name": "actions.devices",
    "deviceControl": {
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "automation"
    }
  }],
  "conversations": {
    "automation" :
    {
      "name": "automation",
      "url": "My ACTION Handler Url API"
    }
  }
}
```

I configure the action

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be clear - is this for a Smart Home action?

Comment: Yes, I added the home work on the title to make it more explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator's default text is incorrect in the case of Smart Home actions. In a house you do not talk *to* your lights and ask them to turn off. You should just say "turn on my lights" without invoking any third-party app.

First, you need to go to the Home Control settings in the Google Assistant settings. There, you can link your Google account to the Smart Home server and SYNC your devices.

After that, you can directly control them without actually passing into a third-party conversation. The simulator does support these commands and will respond correctly once you do the account linking. However, it is different from a conversation.